# how to submit using link with my current code(php+jquery+ajax)

Tags: jquery

My current Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form').ajaxForm( {
            target: '#preview',
            success: function() {
            $('#success_box').addClass('success')   
            setTimeout(function() {
            $('#success_box').fadeOut('slow');
            }, 3100); // <-- time in milliseconds
        } 
    });
}); 
</script>

<form action="controller/product_edit_update.php" method="post" id="form" name="form" >

bla..bla..

<input type="submit" value="Save" /></form>
```

but now i want to add submit link with

```
<a href="" id="submit_with_link" >Save</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try what's in the [docs](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api)?

```
$('#submit_with_link').click(function() {
    $('#form').ajaxSubmit();
});
```

Comment: yes..but its not work(ajaxSubmit) when i put .click(function()

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#submit_with_link').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('form').ajaxSubmit()
})
```

Comment: but i want this function target: '#preview',
            success: function() {
            $('#success_box').addClass('success') bla..bla..